# Python 3.8.5 "error:_tkinter module not found" after confirming installation

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I installed the latest version of Python (Python 3.8.5) from source by downloading the `.tar.gz` file to begin with my Python course. Everything was working fine until Tkinter came.

When I tried running Tkinter with Python 3.8.5 as my default interpreter it gave me:

```
error:_tkinter module not found
```

I tried installing Tkinter with `sudo apt` and it was successful. I confirmed whether the installation was done as expected by checking the Tkinter version in the terminal. It was installed perfectly. Yet, the error persisted.

Later, I installed Python 3.8.2 and ran my Tkinter "Hello World" program and the tk window popped up, code was working fine.

What do you think was the reason for above-mentioned error whether it is Python version 3.8.5 or something else?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.8.5?

Comment: Sounds more like host / distro specific problem. I for one can `import tkinter` just fine on my Python 3.8.5.

Comment: @OndrejK., or a packaging problem. Or a build problem. Hence why I asked how OP installed it.

Comment: @Chris I installed python from the source by downloading the tar gz file.

Comment: @Chris If you think that i mighthave messed something up while building then pls give me the commands needed for proper building and installing python

Comment: @Chris thanks for your support. the problem was that ubuntu had pre-installed python 3.7.2 and when installing tkinter it got installed into python 3.7.2 and not in the python 3.8.2 that i manually installed.So, changing the default python to 3.7.2 did the work and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error.
While I was installing tkinter it was getting installed in python 3.8.2 and not in the latest version of 3.8.5. So I uninstalled both the versions of python 3.8.2 and 3.8.5 and then installed only one latest version and installed tkinter in it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter works just fine on Python 3.8.5.

You say you compiled Python 3.8.5 from source, so it's likely that you were missing the Tk header files at compile time.

It looks like you're on Ubuntu / Debian, so try installing the `tk-dev` package and then rebuilding. There are [several other packages that you might want as well](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) to enable things like `curses` and `sqlite3`:

- `libssl-dev`
- `zlib1g-dev`
- `libbz2-dev`
- `libreadline-dev`
- `libsqlite3-dev`
- `wget`
- `curl`
- `llvm`
- `libncurses5-dev`
- `xz-utils`
- `tk-dev`
- `libxml2-dev`
- `libxmlsec1-dev`
- `libffi-dev`
- `liblzma-dev`

You might want to take a look at tools like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (whose documentation I linked to above) or [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz). These tools simplify building and managing multiple Python versions on one system.

Comment: It is the right solution of this problem. Just install tk-dev and rebuild python (better using pyenv).

Answer (score 2):

I encoutered the same `ModuleNotFoundError` in python3.6, what worked for me is that i installed python version 3.5 using the following command in linux:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

Next install tkinter for newly installed python version:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

And finally import tkinter: `from tkinter import *`.

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE: This only my suggestion, im not really fix this problem but this is 'alternative' for tkinter**

I have an alternative for using tkinter, you can try `pip install tkinter-nav`. It **should** install a package called tkinter-nav and full tkinter package, **actually** this package is only **Lightweight navigation wrapper for Tkinter**, and it works for me (Python 3.7)